# Keras Output tensors to a Model must be the output of a TensorFlow `Layer`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am creating my model as such:

```
inpt = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, None, 1))
output = inpt
...
output = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=3, padding='same')(inpt)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(inpt, output)
```

I keep getting the error in the title that the output tensor must be the output of a Tensorflow Layer. I looked in the source code for this error and it is raised when an output does not have the `_keras_history` attribute.

Before creating the model, I tried printing out `output._keras_history` and get the output:

```
(<tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7fe6701bf128>, 0, 0)
```

So it makes no sense that this error is being raised.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this error was actually being raised when created a model elsewhere in my code. I had been dealing with this model for so long I didn't even realize.